# Why it inserts "?" instead of persian unicode characters?

Tags: sql, sql-server, character-encoding

I am creating an ETL project, in which I want to move a table on an Oracle server into a table on a SQL Server.

I have a `varchar2` column in Oracle, which I mapped to a `varchar` column in SQL Server.

But when I execute the ETL (using Microsoft BI), the data turn into "?".

The original data is persian unicode characters.

Comment: Use `nvarchar` or (possibly) change the collation if there is a suitable code page for the characters you want to store.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/217269/12711

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the table name is `some_table` and the column name is `some_column` of size `100` characters for your SQL Server. Running the following T-SQL command should solve your problem:

```
ALTER TABLE some_table ALTER COLUMN some_column NVARCHAR(100)
```