# LEN and DATALENGTH of VARCHAR and NVARCHAR

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, varchar, nvarchar, datalength

After reading "[What is the difference between char, nchar, varchar, and nvarchar in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176514/what-is-the-difference-between-char-nchar-varchar-and-nvarchar-in-sql-server/8250586)" I have a question.

I'm using MS SQL Server 2008 R2

```sql
DECLARE @T TABLE
(
C1 VARCHAR(20)  COLLATE Chinese_Traditional_Stroke_Order_100_CS_AS_KS_WS,
C2 NVARCHAR(20) COLLATE Chinese_Traditional_Stroke_Order_100_CS_AS_KS_WS
)

INSERT INTO @T VALUES (N'中华人民共和国',N'中华人民共和国')

SELECT LEN(C1)        AS [LEN(C1)],
       DATALENGTH(C1) AS [DATALENGTH(C1)],
       LEN(C2)        AS [LEN(C2)],
       DATALENGTH(C2) AS [DATALENGTH(C2)]
FROM   @T
```

Returns

```
LEN(C1)     DATALENGTH(C1) LEN(C2)     DATALENGTH(C2)
----------- -------------- ----------- --------------
7           12             7           14
```

**Why the second  DATALENGTH(C1) is 12?**

Comment: Is this something to do with the Chinese characters? try doing it on normal characters, I guess it works well.

Answer (score 2):

In your `INSERT` you are converting text from unicode to chinese codepage for `C1`. Most likely this process alters the text and something may be lost.

Here is [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cc9a9/5/0).

You can see that the second character `华` is stored as `3F` in `varchar`. You can also see that the last character `国` is also stored as `3F` in `varchar`. `3F` is a code for `?`. When Windows tries to convert text from unicode to the codepage and certain character can't be represented in the given codepage, the conversion function (most likely [`WideCharToMultiByte`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374130%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) puts `?` for such characters .

One more example. The last, but one character `和` is encoded as `A94D` in `varchar` and `8C54` in `nvarchar`. If you look it up in Character Map it will show these codes (unicode and codepage):

[image: character map]

See also:

[What does it mean when my text is displayed as Question Marks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217237/what-does-it-mean-when-my-text-is-displayed-as-question-marks)

https://www.microsoft.com/middleeast/msdn/Questionmark.aspx

> Any time Unicode data must be displayed, they may be internally
>   converted from Unicode using the WideCharToMultiByte API. Any time a
>   character cannot be represented on the current code page, it will be
>   replaced by a question mark (?).

This is exactly what is happening when you store a unicode literal `N'中华人民共和国'` in a `varchar` column. The unicode text is converted to multi-byte and some characters can't be represented in that code page and they are replaced by question marks `?`.