# C# Debug Property Name displayed as box

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I am getting boxes instead of property/member name while debugging in Visual Studio 2015. And this issue does not occur for all the variables. Please refer the image.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIqIe.png)

I referred the post [What does it mean when my text is displayed as boxes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217228/what-does-it-mean-when-my-text-is-displayed-as-boxes). But it does not help me to set steps to set the font. Any help to fix this issue is much appreciated.

Comment: What language are you variables written in?

Comment: is this in your code or some 3rd party dll?

Comment: Consider using the obfuscator *after* you've debugged the code.

Comment: My application is in c#.I am using 3rd party DLL. I am facing this issue only for 3rd party's.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because your variable names are written in **Unicode**.

Since Visual Studio debugger window does not support Unicode, the only way to solve this issue is to rename your variables to **plain English** (no Unicode characters).

Comment: The members which I see as boxes is Thirdparty Library's. And my team member who is using the same library is not getting the issue.

Comment: @GandhimathiBabu What is your computer's default language set to?

Comment: Default Language set in my computer is English (United States)